# Copy values across relative worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I would like to copy a range of values from one worksheet into a specified range of another worksheet whereas values always come from the *previous* worksheet (in the worksheet row), even after duplicating the worksheet. I'm using the following to copy values from one worksheet to the other, which seems to work:

```
Sub Copy_ultimo_stock()

'copy values between two periods
Worksheets("Period2").Range("test3").Value = Worksheets("Period1").Range("test2").Value

End Sub
```

I had to give the range of cells a name (test2 and test3), because the macro wouldn't work if I use the actual cell range like "R10:S11". In the future however, I would just like to use the cell range as "R10:S11".

My actual problem however is the following. If I duplicate my worksheets in the future (for future periods), I want that I always copy the cell range from the *previous* worksheet. The way I have done it now, if I copy the worksheet period2, and call it maybe period6, it will still copy values from period1 worksheet. However, I would like that the current worksheet "n" will copy values from the range in worksheet "n-1".

I have found a somewhat similar approach that could help, but I couldn't combine both macros into one. That approach is here:

```
Function PrevSheet(rCell As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Integer
    i = rCell.Cells(1).Parent.Index
    PrevSheet = Sheets(i - 1).Range(rCell.Address)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

So you requirement is a macro that imports from "the previous sheet", so that when you click the button, the subroutine first fetches the previous from the current and accordingly fetches the values.

We will suppose that all Worksheets are named like "periodx", where x is an integer identifying the period. when we create a new worksheet copy, we need first to rename the new worksheet in the form "periodx" and then click on the button to fetch the values from the sheet "periody" where y = x-1.

Just replace your button handler `Copy_ultimo_stock()` with this one:

```
Sub Copy_ultimo_stock()
    Dim wsCur As Worksheet, wsPrev As Worksheet
    Set wsCur = ActiveSheet
    ' We will suppose that all Worksheets are named like "periodx"
    ' where x is an integer identifying the period
    On Error Resume Next ' try fetching the previous ws as "periody" where y = x-1
    Dim x As Integer: x = CInt(Mid(wsCur.Name, Len("period") + 1))
    Set wsPrev = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("period" & (x - 1))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       msgBox "Could not find the previous worksheet, Please check Worksheet names"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Now we copy the previous values. You can customize the ranges if the design changes
    wsCur.Range("D2:L8").Value = wsPrev.Range("D10:L16").Value

End Sub
```

Moreover, you can automate the generation of a new period worksheet by adding another button, say "Generate Next Period", that will create the new ws and give it the appropriate name. This will save the user the task of copying the sheet and renaming it. The code for the new button will be like this:

```
Sub create_next_period()
    Dim wsCur As Worksheet, wsNext As Worksheet
    Set wsCur = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim x As Integer: x = CInt(Mid(wsCur.Name, Len("period") + 1))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       msgBox "Please check Worksheet name. It should be named periodx"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsNext = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("period" & (x + 1))
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
       msgBox "The worksheet " & wsNext.Name & " already exists"
       Exit Sub
    Else
        Err.Clear
        wsCur.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNext = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        wsNext.Name = "period" & (x + 1)
        wsNext.Activate
        Call Copy_ultimo_stock
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'm basically illiterate when it comes to VBA, I'm having trouble to understand your suggestion. The VBA parts I used in my own post and in the excel file were just copied from other users who have explained how to do it. I'm not able to modify anything in an existing VBA really.

Would it be possible to write the VBA code so that I can copy it and it will work in my file? Then I would just change the ranges so they match my cells.

I'm aware that my method is quite sensitive to the order of the sheets. They will be named according to months, so that will help.

Comment: @Jauheliha I feel I did not quite get your objective. I think that now I have some better idea, but I suggest that you show some snapshot of the worsheets and how the cells relate to each other. My feeling now is that you want something like, say, in sheet3, cell `F4` would be equal to cell `E4` in previous sheet, something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous input ASH! I have some screenshots here to help you understand my problem. I reduced the screenshot to the essential part. the Actual excel file is a bit more complex, but this should be enough to get the idea.
You can see sheets for period 1,2 and 3. What my makro does after clicking, it copies values from "Period 1 Current Period" into "Period 2 Previous period". This works well. HOWEVER: if I copy the sheet "Period 2" and name it "Period 3" (which I have done), and then click the button...
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mtki4lf39gealha/AADssIuEq4IVJ47yE46ZAWxIa?dl=0

Comment: ...in sheet `Period 3`, it will copy the values from `Period 1`. My desire however is, that it would take values from `Period 2`. In the future, there will be dozens of more sheets to be created. My ultimate aim is therefore, to copy values always from the **previous** sheet, not an absolut sheet reference like `Period 1`. Because than I would have to change the macro every time I duplicate a sheet. It's kind of like a rollover of material from one period into the next just by clicking the button. (I know in this case it looks like you could just `CTRL+C` the values, but the actual model...

Comment: ... is a bit more complicated than that). So hopefully you can help me with the macro for that option. And hopefully I could help you  understand my wish.

Comment: @Jauheliha Good explanation, I see now. I will think about it and try to come up with a simple and robust solution. By the way, is it ok that the macro imports only values to the current ws from the previous? Or does it need to be a formula in order to reflect immediately any changes that happen in the previous?

Comment: @Jauheliha please see the last edit. You now have a macro that copies from previous sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and investing your time into this ASH!!
I will try this as soon as I back in the office on Monday. I have taken a look at the macro description and it looks like it's what I was looking for.

To answer your previous questions: the values don't have to be synchronised to whatever happens in the previous WS, they can be static, so this is perfect.
I see that this one is now working with `PeriodX` as worksheet names and I also like the idea to copy the WS automatically! I'll let you know on Monday if I could implement it successfully. Thanks so much!

Comment: The macro to copy the stock works like a charm, thanks!
I have tried to also use the macro to create the next period, but it only copied the specified cell range, but not the formatting or all the other cells in the worksheet (The worksheet is bigger and has more tables than the excerpt shown in the screenshot). I found another way though, which goes like this:
`Sub CopySheet_End()
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End Sub`
Only problem is that the worksheets are not named correctly...

Comment: ... that has to be done manually. Any idea on how to include a line so that the name of the new ws is called PeriodX (where X is +1 than the last ws)?

Comment: Yeah, sure. For some reason I cant upload the edit. Your modification is good, do this: `wsCur.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNext = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`

Comment: @Jauheliha please see the edit. I prefer you keep it this way, because the code captures the name of the current period to rename the next one and it also checks if the next period already exists.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your help! I copied the macro from your edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you name your cells do:

Range("whatever").name="Sheet!Name"

and not just

Range("whatever").name="Name"

==> this way you can gave the same named range on several sheets without any problem

Hope this helps.

However I wouldn't advice using too much named ranges...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would also prefer to go without any named ranges, but in this case I had to give the range a name, because it wouldn't work otherwise for some reason.